# Why the value of my variable has changed from the function without explicitly passed by reference in OOP?

Tags: php, oop, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I know that in procedural PHP if you want to change the value of a variable from a function you need to pass it by reference using '&'. The default mode for passing variables into a function is passing by value. Why then I have got my variable changed in OOP by default. Why it is acting like pass by reference?

```
class BankAccount {
    public $balance = 10;
    public function Withdraw($amount){
        return $this->balance = $this->balance - $amount;
        }

}

$john= new BankAccount();
$john-> Withdraw(3); 
echo $john->balance;
```

The result is 7. The value of my variable is changed from the function without explicitly passing by reference.

Comment: Objects are not copied.

Comment: You have `$this->balance = $this->balance - $amount;` in your `Withdraw` function. Why are you expecting `$this->balance` not to be `7`?

Comment: Because I didn't echo my Withdraw function, but my variable. When I make a similar process in a procedural way it gives me of course 7 when I echo my Withdraw function, but it doesn't change my variable when I echo it.

Comment: but your `Withdraw` function changes the variable... it's as if you wrote `function wd($amt) { global $x; return $x = $x - $amt; } $x = 10; wd(3); echo $x;`

Comment: It is getting clearer. But I have been avoiding global because I had been told it is a bad practice. Instead, I use to pass a value by reference if I want to change its value from the function. Like this: function Withdraw(&$balance,$amount){//some code;}

Comment: `$john->balance` is a reference to the property `balance` that belongs to the instantiation of `BankAccount` named `$john`. Any time you change the property’s value, all references to it also reflect the change. It has to be that way for an object to work. Remember scope- the property is in the scope of the object. So any time you reference the object, you get exactly what the object holds.

Comment: Actually, your only local variable, `$john`, was technically never changed. The value that `$john` holds is a reference, i.e. a pointer to an object. "Objects" are not values in their own right in PHP5. In PHP5, objects are always manipulated through references. When you do `new BankAccount(...)` that evaluates to a reference (pointer to an object). When you use the `->` operator, it takes a reference (pointer to an object) on the left side. This reference never changed -- it still points to the same object. (continued)

Comment: The object that the reference points to may have changed, but that is not the same as the variable itself changing. If you were to change the `$john` variable by assigning to it, you can make it point to a different object, to hold a different type of value altogether.